# Escape apostrophe is not working

Tags: javascript, php, replace

I have found some questions like this one,but unfortunately,none of the solutions solved my problem.

Here is what I'm doing(also tried with `json_encode`.Didn't work either)

**PHP**

```
$head="<div id='headx'>".htmlspecialchars($headu)."<input type='submit' id='edit_head' value='Edit' onclick='edit_title9(this.id,\"".htmlspecialchars($headu,ENT_QUOTES)."\")'></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
 function edit_title9(ya,va1){

   var divid = document.getElementById(ya).parentNode.id;
   var cola=ya;
   var val1=va1.replace(/'/g,"\'");

   alert(val1);  //works fine

   document.getElementById(divid).innerHTML="<input type='text'  id='taxi1' width='40px' value='"+val1+"' >";
 }
```

when I use `alert(val1)`,it works fine and show `'` on the line,but in the `text field`,I get only upto `apostrophe(exclusive)` and the rest is removed.

But when I use other characters it shows nicely in `text field`.

```
va1.replace(/'/g,"\A");
```

gives `heAs good` for `he's good` on text field.

Why is that happening and how can I get rid of this?

Comment: change your `.replace` to replace with the value `\\\'`. It is likely you need to double escape the replacement value.

Comment: Or event better, set the innerHTML and on the next line `getElementById('theID').value=val1` without the replace. Or simply use DOM calls.

Comment: `\\\'` didn't work.Gives me `he\\` and rest is removed

Comment: I need to do this,which might not be possible using `getElementById('theID').value=val1`.This is what I do with the text field `document.getElementById(divid).innerHTML="<input type='text'  id='taxi1' width='40px' value='"+val1+"' required><input type='submit' id='' onclick='change9(taxi1.value,"+divid+")' value='done'>";`

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Looking forward to get your help.Thanks

Comment: My second comment was meaning after you do the innerHTML to `divid` that input element is now in the document and you can find it using document.getElementById() and set it's value. That is just one way. You could also replace with the html entity which is `&apos;` (or `&#39;`, same thing) like `.replace(/'/, '&apos;');` which would work. Doing a quick test it worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running a quick test, what worked for me was to change your replacement value to the html entity. Ex:

```
var val1=va1.replace(/'/g,"&#39;");
```

The string (prior to setting the value) will show the html entity but the input's value will be the decoded entity.